# Unable to pass data to another webpage React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to transfer data from one web page to another.  In web-page-2, I am getting back itemData as 'undefined' and I do not understand why.  Please can someone advise?

```
// web-page-1
class A extends Component {
    state = {
    data: {}
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        data: this.props.myData
    })
}
    render()}
    <Link 
         to={{pathname: "/item-details", state:{data: data}}}
}
}

// web-page-2
class B extends Component {
     state = {
         itemData: {}
     }
componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({
        itemData: this.props.location.state.data
      })
}
    
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <Header />
            <Breadcrumb title="Stone Details" subpage="Explore" page="Item Details" />
            <ItemDetail />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass data through a Link in react-router you have to follow this convention from the documentation in class A (https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link):

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/item-details",
    state: { data: item }
  }}
/>
```

The data will then be available on the page in class B, you can access it like this:

```
this.props.location.state.data
```

Not sure if you cleaned up the code, but your class A has no render function nor return so this has to be working as well.

Comment: @lvo I have updated my question incorporating your solution. however, I am getting back 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')' when I try and set the itemData to 'this.props.location.state.data' on webe-page-2

Comment: I think the Link part is good but your component are not proper React component. Initiate the state as mentioned by @BIPUL MANDOL in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, passing state from one page to another page is ok. But I think the problem is initializing the state in-class component. The state of a component must be initialized in the constructor.
A sample of initializing state ....

```
class A() extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: "empty"
        }
    }


  return (
      <h1 className="Title">{this.state.value}</h1>
  );
}
```